# Hide android statusbar across all apps

Tags: android

I wanted to ask how I can make the android statusbar hidden across all apps. Yes i know this will need root and I also know that there are questions similar to this, but those are only for **one** app, not for all. I used this but it didnt work:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: You are talking about overriding the android OS. I know you would have to either create a custom home screen, with no status bar. Or override the android home screen layout to not show the bar. In either case, I don't know how to approach this, but I know the general concept :) Good luck.

Comment: @LuckyMe Yeah thats the case, tho there is a way to kill the systemui, which would also stop the recent apps on 4.0+ to stop working, but I was looking was looking for a way around that to maintain functionality

Comment: @LuckyMe the status bar is not drawn my the launcher (home screen) app. having root is not enough here ... you need to roll a custom ROM and disable the status bar therein (which is probably not trivial).